# Generic Enablers mismatch

Tags: fiware, fractals, fiware-poi

I'm stuck with answering on one specific question in FRACTALS form:
What technical infrastructure does your proposal use (or will it use)?

I have these checkboxes offered:

1. Applications/Services Ecosystems and Delivery Framework
2. Cloud Hosting
3. Data/Context Management
4. Interface to Networks and Devices
5. Internet of Things Services Enabement
6. Security

I am planning to use the POI Data Provider, and I am not sure which item to check. 
In catalog the POI Data Provider GE is in "Advanced Web-based User Interface" category, but that category isn't on form.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

POI Data Provider belongs to the  "Advanced Web-based User Interface" which was earlier called "MiWi Advanced Middleware and Web-based UI". This was included later in the FIWARE selection. If you cannot find either in the FRACTALS form, please contact them directly to add it there, or use their discussion forum here: http://www.f6s.com/fiware-fractals#/discuss